# Windows Phone UnautorizedAccessExeption when using Task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I try using Task object to run code asynchronously:

```
public void buttonAnswer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task t = new Task(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            MessageBox.Show("Test..");
        });

        t.Start();
    }
```

But when run application on device i get UnautorizedAccessExeption exeption on `MessageBox.Show("Test..");` line.

[visual studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmVy4.png)

Comment: Add this line at the beginning of click handler method `var syncContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();`. Start task `t` by passing synchronization context - `t.Start(syncContext)`.

Comment: @Michael That will make the `Thread.Sleep` run in UI thread - which is a bad thing to do.

Comment: @Michael Thank you ) this really work!

Comment: @ned I don't recommend doing that. If you opt for it, you're executing the Task in the UI thread. Which means that `Thread.Sleep` or any processing code you have there will also run in UI thread which will freeze the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the user interface elements in background thread. You should marshal the call to the UI thread instead.

Using async/await it's fairly simple thing to do.

```
public async void buttonAnswer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Your heavy processing here. Runs in threadpool thread
    });
    MessageBox.Show("Test..");//This runs in UI thread.
}
```

If you can't use async/await, you can use `Dispatcher.Invoke`/`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` methods to execute the code in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael comment solution:

```
public void buttonAnswer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var syncContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            Task t = new Task(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                MessageBox.Show("Test..");
            });

            t.Start(syncContext);
        }
```